# How can I pass a variable to a function every time I assign it to a different value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make my own simple round progress bar to understand arrays and functions more.

I googled some questions, but couldn't find what I need.

Everything works fine so far, except for only one thing.

the function `fill()` takes the first given `skillPercent` and applies it on all array's elements.

how can I make it change each element according to its given `skillPercent`.

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll(".divb");
var i = d.length;

while (i--) {
  if (d[i].className.includes("1")) {
    skillPercent = 40;
    fill(d[i]);
  }

  if (d[i].className.includes("2")) {
    skillPercent = 70;
    fill(d[i]);
  }

  if (d[i].className.includes("3")) {
    skillPercent = 90;
    fill(d[i]);
  }

  function fill(item) {
    percent = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      if (percent == skillPercent) {
        clearInterval(item);
      } else {
        percent += 0.5;
        item.style.background = "conic-gradient( #ff5555 " + percent + "%, #000 0%)";
      }
    }, 30);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.div {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px;
  background: #555;
}

.divb {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  /* background: conic-gradient(#00ff00 30deg, #000 0deg); */
}
```

```html
<div class="divb 1">
  <div class="div">skill1</div>
</div>

<div class="divb 2">
  <div class="div">skill2</div>
</div>

<div class="divb 3">
  <div class="div">skill3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Comment: `function fill(item, skillParent)` usage: `fill(d[i], 40);`

Comment: _"...to its given `skillPercent`."_ - There's only one `skillPercent`. If you want to have different, independent, `skillPercent`s then you have to find a way to make them independent: separate variables, pass them to `fill()` without a global variable, ...

Comment: If I can find the way, I won't ask here. I've been trying for 3 days. but thanks for the suggestions. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Danny Yuan, I found that I only need to do two things:

1. Declare percent in the function.
2. Pass skillPercent in the function.

that's it.

```js
var d = document.querySelectorAll(".divb");
var i = d.length;

while (i--) {

    if (d[i].className.includes("1")) {
        skillPercent = 40;
        fill(d[i], skillPercent);
    }

    if (d[i].className.includes("2")) {
        skillPercent = 70;
        fill(d[i], skillPercent);
    }

    if (d[i].className.includes("3")) {
        skillPercent = 90;
        fill(d[i], skillPercent);
    }
    
    function fill(item, skillPercent) {
        var percent = 1;
        setInterval(() => {
            if (percent == skillPercent) {
                clearInterval();
            }
            else {
                percent++;
                item.style.background = "conic-gradient( #ff5555 " + percent + "%, #000 0%)";
            }
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

```css
.body {
    display: inline-flex;
}

.div {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1px;
    background: #555;
}

.divb {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
    <div class="divb 1">
        <div class="div">skill1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="divb 2">
        <div class="div">skill2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="divb 3">
        <div class="div">skill3</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to firstly define your variables properly either with const, var or let.

You can pass the skillPercent variable into the function which therefore makes the skillPercent unique for each div as Konrad Linkowski said

Then assign the interval as a variable so you can clear it later.
Finally, I have slighly adjusted your code so that it reloads every frame and not the slightly "hacky" way of using setInterval at frame rates (but I left in comments if you want it that way too).

```
var d = document.querySelectorAll(".divb");
var i = d.length;

while (i--) {
  if (d[i].className.includes("1")) {
    const skillPercent = 40;
    fill(d[i], skillPercent);
  }

  if (d[i].className.includes("2")) {
    const skillPercent = 70;
    fill(d[i], skillPercent);
  }

  if (d[i].className.includes("3")) {
    const skillPercent = 90;
    fill(d[i], skillPercent);
  }

  function fill(item, skillPercent) {
    var percent = 1;
    // Perhaps you should use request animation instead of setInterval

    // Request animation frame
    // Whenever requestAnimationFrame is called, the code inside is executed on the next frame loaded. 
    // It was made so that different refresh rates doesn't impact the code as much.
    requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame)
    function nextFrame() {
        if (percent == skillPercent) {
            return // return will mean this function is not called again, thus stopping the animation
        } else {
            percent += 0.5;
            item.style.background = "conic-gradient( #ff5555 " + percent + "%, #000 0%)";
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(nextFrame) // Executes again in the next frame
    }
    // Request animation frame
    

    // Set interval 
    /*
    const myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (percent == skillPercent) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      } else {
        percent += 0.5;
        item.style.background = "conic-gradient( #ff5555 " + percent + "%, #000 0%)";
      }
    }, 30);*/
    // Set interval
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer works, but I found that I only need to do two things, thanks to you Danny:
1-- declare percent in the function. 2-- pass skillPercent in the function. that's it.